# Warning: React does not recognize the `viewState` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

I manipulate component's state and use the objects in state (the input params) to display some information.

```js
const renderTooltip = ({ object: hoveredObject, x: pointerX, y: pointerY }) => {
  // console.log(hoveredObject);
  const {points} = hoveredObject;

  const calLoadTime = () => {
    const rawTime = points.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => 
      currentValue ? accumulator + currentValue.SPACES : accumulator, 
      0
    ) / points.length;

    return rawTime.toFixed(1);
  }

  return (
    <span
      style={{
        lineHeight: '20px',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        width: '200px',
        left: pointerX+10,
        top: pointerY+5,
      }}
    >
      {`Length: ${points.length}\n`}
    </span>
  )
}
```

But got following warning, I checked I didn't manipulate state on a DOM element, or have some property named `viewState`? What does the warning means?

> Warning: React does not recognize the `viewState` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `viewstate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

The full code of my component shows below:

```js
import React, { memo, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import DeckGL, {HexagonLayer} from 'deck.gl';
import { StaticMap } from 'react-map-gl';

import { INITIAL_VIEW_STATE, LAYER_CONFIGS } from './configs';
import { addMapControl } from './tools';
import { MAPBOX_TOKEN } from './constants';
import styles from './index.less';

const Map = (props) => {
  const {
    controller = true,
    baseMap = true,
    initialViewState = INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
    layerType = '3d-heatmap',
    renderTooltip = DEFAULT_RENDER_TOOLTIP,
  } = props;

  const [tooltip, setTooltip] = useState({
    object: null,
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unused-state
    x: 0,
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unused-state
    y: 0,
  })

  /**
   * layers render function
   */
  const renderLayers = () => {
    const {
      data,
      accData = [],
      accSpeed = 0.1,
      accRadiusScale = 4,
      accRadiusMaxPixels = 200,
      accColorRange,
      coverage = 1,
      radius,
      elevationScale,
      ...otherProps
    } = props;
    const layers = [];

    layers.push(
      new HexagonLayer({
        ...LAYER_CONFIGS.AugmentHexagonLayer,
        ...otherProps,
        coverage,
        data,
        radius,
        onHover: setTooltip,
      }),
    );

    return layers;
  }

  /**
   * add Control for language switching
   * @param {*} event 
   */
  const addControlHandler = (event) => {
    const map = event && event.target;
    if (map) {
      addMapControl(map);
    }
  };

  const { object } = tooltip || {};

  return (
    <DeckGL
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      layers={renderLayers()} // eslint-disable-line
      initialViewState={initialViewState}
      controller={controller}
    >
      {baseMap && (
        <StaticMap
          onLoad={addControlHandler}
          reuseMaps
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
          preventStyleDiffing
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        />
      )}
      {object && renderTooltip(tooltip)}
    </DeckGL>
  );
}
```

I used some third-party package to make tooltip display in maps.

The `renderTooltip` props is assigned by the input `renderTooltip` function I mentioned above, and I use `tooltip` state to control whether I should display tooltip in my page.

PS: according the documents of deck.gl, the `onHover` will be triggered at:

> onHover (Function, optional)
>
> This callback will be called when the mouse enters/leaves an object of this deck.gl layer with the following parameters:
>
> - info
> - event - the source event

According to the error trace path, it throw the error in my `<span>` element, that's why I think it's the `renderTooltip`'s problem at first.

```js
Warning: React does not recognize the `viewState` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `viewstate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in span (created by Map)
    in div (created by DeckGL)
    in div (created by DeckGL)
    in DeckGL (created by Map)
    in Map (created by SpatialTemporal)
    in section (created by SpatialTemporal)
    in SpatioMap
    in section
    in Unknown (created by LBS)
    in div
    in div
    in Unknown (created by LBS)
    in LBS (created by Connect(LBS))
    in Connect(LBS) (created by DynamicComponent)
    in DynamicComponent (created by Route)
    in Route (created by BasicLayout)
    in Switch (created by BasicLayout)
    in div (created by BasicLayout)
    in div (created by Basic)
    in Basic (created by Adapter)
    in Adapter (created by BasicLayout)
    in div (created by BasicLayout)
    in BasicLayout (created by Adapter)
    in Adapter (created by BasicLayout)
    in div (created by BasicLayout)
    in BasicLayout (created by Adapter)
    in Adapter (created by BasicLayout)
    in div (created by ContainerQuery)
    in ContainerQuery (created by BasicLayout)
    in DocumentTitle (created by SideEffect(DocumentTitle))
    in SideEffect(DocumentTitle) (created by BasicLayout)
    in BasicLayout (created by Connect(BasicLayout))
    in Connect(BasicLayout) (created by DynamicComponent)
    in DynamicComponent (created by Route)
    in Route (created by DvaRoot)
    in Switch (created by DvaRoot)
    in Router (created by DvaRoot)
    in LocaleProvider (created by DvaRoot)
    in Provider (created by DvaRoot)
    in DvaRoot
```

Comment: Could you please you show code of the component?

Comment: I don't think this is the part of the code of the warning is coming from

Comment: @HaiPham Thanks for reminding! I used some third-party package to make tooltip display in maps, and I implement it at the bottom of description, I make it more clear by remove some useless codes. :-)

Comment: @aquilesb The same as the content above. Thanks very much. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today and solved it by NOT adding the tooltip as a direct child of deckGL:

```js
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <DeckGL
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      layers={renderLayers()} // eslint-disable-line
      initialViewState={initialViewState}
      controller={controller}
    >
      {baseMap && (
        <StaticMap
          onLoad={addControlHandler}
          reuseMaps
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
          preventStyleDiffing
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        />
      )}
    </DeckGL>
    {object && renderTooltip(tooltip)}
 </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: I tried this way and got warning in setting state with `onHover` callback. Did you get the same situation before?

Answer (score 0):

It's seem like this warning come from deck.gl, try modifying `Map` component:

```
const Map = (props) => {
  const {
    controller = true,
    baseMap = true,
    initialViewState = INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
    layerType = '3d-heatmap',
    renderTooltip = DEFAULT_RENDER_TOOLTIP,
    ...rest //rest props
  } = props;
//...
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question, should I use the `rest` object in somewhere, otherwise why should I rest useless properties to another object? Is it belongs to deck.gl's internal problem?

Comment: I tried to rest other unused properties, and I will still get errors when I move mouse to display tooltips, but not always, just sometimes when I refreshing the page.

Comment: I see logic error here: `{object && renderTooltip(tooltip)}`. It your if (object) will be true event if it's `{}`, please try fixing this and refresh

Comment: I do notice this logic, however I think it will never be assigned `{}`, since I initialize it in the beginning with `useState`, though I use `const { object } = tooltip || {};` in the render part.

Comment: @hijiangtao it's compicated, I'm not familiar to deck.gl, so could you please create an https://codesandbox.io/ project to make it easy for tracing?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was running into the same issue. This is a subtle one, but it appears as though you are not supposed to pass the rendered tooltip through as a child of DeckGL, but rather, as a function that will render the tooltip when called. So, in your case, you could do this:

```
  return (
    <DeckGL
      ...
    >
      ...
      {object && renderTooltip.bind(this, tooltip)}
    </DeckGL>
  );
```

The call to `bind` lets you curry the argument you wanted to pass in without actually calling the underlying function. Any props passed by DeckGL will be passed as the next argument after `tooltip`.

There are other ways to solve this too, but the key is to pass a function that will render not a rendered component.